# Was the origin positioning 'box' removed from Xcode 6?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode6

[image: Xcode 'Origin' tool]

I don't see this tool in Xcode 6. Did they take it out? Can I re-enable it? I use it all the time.

Comment: AFAIK it has. You really should be using AutoLayout by now though. Especially with Xcode 6 and size classes. Without them you will be left behind.

Comment: I do use autolayout. But I usually position my views the way I want it on a specific screen, pixel for pixel, and then add the autolayout constraints after. Seems silly to take it out just to enforce the use of autolayout. It still has its uses.

Comment: Right, this doesn't relate to supporting autolayout. It's simply used to make it easier to move things around when you're placing things on storyboard.

Comment: Any new info on this?

Comment: Nope. We might be out of luck. I have come up with a new system for positioning my subviews though. What I've started doing instead is I'll add all my subviews and ctrl+drag all the constraints I need, completely ignoring if they are positioned correctly. Then I just go through each constraint and edit the constant value. When Xcode yells at me for all my misplaced views: Update Frame -> Apply to all views in container. It's actually kind of satisfying to see all of your views snap into place all at once!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's so old, it's completely irrelevant and there is no answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 6 had an `origin positioning` box but newer versions of Xcode, including Xcode 11 and later, have adopted a more streamlined layout system known as `Auto Layout`.

Shift to `Auto Layout`, the `origin positioning` box was deprecated and removed from the Xcode user interface. It is not available in modern versions of Xcode, and there is no built-in way to re-enable it.